# VBA SaveAs to .xlsm does not contain any macro modules

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that basically makes a copy of the current file, and save it to users' "Downloads" folder.

However, while the `SaveAs` works, the output does not contain any modules. Instead, they are all linked to the exporting file.

```
Sub PushToProduction()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
    ' save a copy of current file to the Downloads folder
    outputPath = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads\"
    d = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
    fileName = outputPath & "REDACTED " & d & " v1.00.xlsm"
    
   ' prepare to save a copy of the file without the last tab
    sheetCount = Application.Sheets.Count - 1
    Dim tabs() As String
    ReDim tabs(1 To sheetCount)
    For i = 1 To sheetCount
        tabs(i) = Worksheets(i).Name
    Next
    
    Worksheets(tabs).Copy
    
   
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox ("Success!")
End Sub
```

The output does not even have the "Modules" folder.

[image: Folders attached to the output]

Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: Unable to reproduce this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzw3N.png. Are you sure the `ActiveWorkbook` is what you think it is?

Comment: Try using a variable instead of the `ActiveWorkbook` or at least a `With` statement. Without seeing the rest of the code it's hard to give any good advice. What is the reason behind using `XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` instead of just `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`?

Comment: Hi sorry guys, I added more codes to the body of the function. Basically, there's a chunk of code where I copies all tabs except the last one, and hoping to store those sheets to the output file.

Comment: There you have it: `Worksheets(tabs).Copy` will just copy the sheets, no standard modules. You'll have to think of a different approach. Since sheets and worksheets are different collections, you should stick to one of them.

Comment: @VBasic2008 So I guess I will just open the output file, and delete the last tab to achieve the same result? Please write an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Are you trying to save the same workbook that contains this code or are they two different workbooks? Will you allow to overwrite an existing workbook?

Comment: It would be the same workbook that contains this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create a Workbook Copy and Modify It

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PushToProduction()
 
    Dim dFolderPath As String
    dFolderPath = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads\"
    Dim d As String: d = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
    Dim dFilePath As String
    dFilePath = dFolderPath & "REDACTED " & d & " v1.00.xlsm"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Workbook ('swb').
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Save a copy of the Source Workbook.
    If StrComp(dFilePath, swb.FullName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You are trying save a copy of the file to the same location.", _
            vbCritical, "Push to Production"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    swb.SaveCopyAs dFilePath
    
    ' Open the copy, the Destination Workbook ('dwb'), remove its last sheet
    ' and close saving the changes.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(dFilePath)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Success!", vbInformation, "Push to Production"
    
    ' Explore Destination Folder.
    'swb.FollowHyperlink dFolderPath
    
End Sub
```